# How can I extract feed forward loops from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, bioinformatics

In this data frame, columns names are also in row name. columns are regulators and their regulation is shown as 1 regulating and 0 not regulating.

| row names | cat1 | cat6 | cat2 | cat5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| cat1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| cat6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

According to this data frame, cat0 is under regulation of cat6 and cat5, because it has 1 for cat6 and cat5 columns. cat6 is also under regulation of cat5. cat6 is also in the rows and has 1 for cat5, whcih makes a feed forward loop. the logic for feed forward loop is node1 ---> node2, node2 ----> node3, node1 ----> node3.
here, in this data frame, cat5 ----> cat6, cat6 ----> cat0, cat5 ----->cat0.

```
def find_ffls(df):
    
    ffls = []
    ffl_count = 0
    for col1 in df.columns:
        for col2 in df.columns:
             if col1 != col2:
                  ffl = ((df[col1] == 1) & (df[col2] == 1)).sum()
                  if ffl > 0:
                      ffls.append((col1, col2))
                      ffl_count += 1

    return ffls, ffl_count

ffls, ffl_count = find_ffls(df)
print("Found FFLs:")
for ffl in ffls:
    print(ffl)
print("Total FFLs found: ", ffl_count)
```

I could not define the regulation of node1 -----> node2.
please help me with writing a python script (python function) to extract all ffls from this data frame.

Answer (score 0):

What you call "feed forward loops" is a form of transitivity. What you're trying to calculate is the transitive closure on the regulators.

One intuitive way to model transitive behavior is to represent it as a graph. If we consider the regulators to be nodes, we can represent "node1 regulates node2" as a directed edge from nodes node1 to node2. The transitive closure of a graph G is a graph with the same nodes, and edges between nodes `a` and `b` only if there exists a path from `a` to `b` in G.

My solution uses `networkx` to construct a graph and get its transitive closure. The reason I chose graphs is because your dataframe looks very much like an adjacency matrix.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({"row names": ['cat0', 'cat1', 'cat6'],
                    "cat1": [0,0,1],
                    "cat6": [1,1,0],
                    "cat2": [0,1,0],
                    "cat5": [1,0,1]
                   },).set_index("row names")

# adding missing rows and columns for the
# adjacency matrix
index = set(df.index)
columns = set(df.columns)

missing_columns = list(index.difference(columns))
df[missing_columns] = 0

missing_rows = list(columns.difference(index))
missing_rows = pd.DataFrame(index=missing_rows)
df = pd.concat((df, missing_rows))
df.loc[missing_rows.index] = 0
df = df.astype(int)

# creating a directed graph from the pandas dataframe
# since networkx uses i->j convention but we have j->i,
# we need to reverse the graph to get the right edges
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df, create_using=nx.DiGraph).reverse()

# remove None if you want to consider catN -> catN is a valid FFL
G_closure = nx.transitive_closure(G, reflexive=None)
number_ffls = len(G_closure.edges()) - len(G.edges())
```

First we need to make sure that every regulator in the columns is also in the index, and vice-versa. That way we have a full adjacency matrix. We do that by adding the needed empty (full of 0s) rows and columns.

After that we create the graph and calculate its transitive closure. The `reflexive` argument is important. It determines whether loops are allowed (i.e. a regulator regulating itself because of an FFL).

The number of FFLs is simply the difference between the number of edges in the transitive closure and the original graph. That's because the transitive closure of G contains all the edges of G, and we're only interested in "new" edges.